# Why isn't Word aligning Justified pasted text from a PDF?

Tags: microsoft-word, pdf, copy-paste, newlines

I copied and pasted the first few paras. from [this PDF](http://ceur-ws.org/Vol-2163/paper1.pdf). Pls see screenshots below. After I clicked to align justified, why didn't each line  automatically fill up to the end?

[image]

Comment: Each line is coming in as a separate paragraph - and I suspect if paragraph is less than one line, no justification is applied to its text.  You could select each block you want to join back up as a single paragraph, and use find and and replace to replace ^p and replace those with space.  Repeat for each block.  Then when you apply the justification to the document it should behave as you expect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [comment by Tanya](https://superuser.com/questions/1530721/why-isnt-word-aligning-justified-pasted-text-from-a-pdf/1535191#comment2323219_1530721) is on the right track.

When a paragraph is justified, all lines except for the last span the whole width.
The last line is not expanded.

The case mentioned by Tanya is a particular case, where the paragraph is one line long.

When you copy from the PDF, it inserts line breaks at the end of every **displayed** line, where the original text had no line breaks.
So while the paragraphs are actually justified, each PDF-displayed-line becomes a single paragraph.

To fix the text there are several options.
Tanya gave one.
I typically use one that I find significantly more efficient:

1. At every place where you actually want a line break, write a sequence of characters (maybe a single one) that you are sure it does not show up in the text.
   In the example below, an asterisk `*` (in red). In the unlikely case your text has a lot of (combinations of) special characters, you would use something really strange, such as `§ª`.
2. Search and replace: Search -> More -> Special -> Paragrpah Mark (or `^p`), Replace with -> (space). Replace all.
3. Search and replace: Search -> `*` (an asterisk followed by a space, added in the previous step), Replace with -> More -> Special -> Paragrpah Mark (or `^p`). Replace all.
   Note: The paragraph mark is red due to my use of coloring for demonstration purposes. You would not have it.

Example:

1. [image]
2. [image]
3. [image]

Comment: Thanks. In 2, do I actually type "line break" and "space" in the fields? If not, what exactly do I input?

Comment: Can you please respond in, by editing, your answer? Comment chains are
cumbersome to read.

Comment: @Edge - Please see edited answer.

Answer (score 1):

You have paragraph markers in the copied text.
To get rid of them is hard and sometimes nasty. You do it via the 
search & replace function in Word
In the find field you enter this characters (special search character for paragraph)

```
^p
```

in the replace field you enter a single space (press the spacebar on the keyboard once)

 Then reformat as you need. So much for the beginner version.
If you have a full/student version of Acrobat > v8 there is an export function (Special save as word file). Advantage you get all images, tables and formats to word.
 If you have no Acrobat version get one of the free pdf exporters around depending on your OS version.
Two words of warning: If the pdf is protected, there is for a normal user no way to get the content even copied. If you copy others work give them credit by citing correctly. As a lecturer I have a software to check the work of my students and more than one was kicked out of university for copy and pasting in scientific work.